# Trigger Collinder doesnt work with Input.GetKey

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I'm trying to make a game where u can cut down trees, but when I tested my script it didn't work at all. This script is for cutting down trees. When I put TakeDmg and Destroytree in the private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) it works fine, but when I add if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)), it stops working I really don't know that's the problem.

```
public int treeHp;
public GameObject logPrefab;
public Animator anim;


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)){

        TakeDmg();
        Destroytree();
    }
}
public void TakeDmg(){
    anim.SetTrigger("TreeDamage");    
    treeHp = treeHp -1;
}

public void Destroytree(){

    if(treeHp <= 0){
        //spawn la loguri 

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code would require the User to already **hold down** the <kbd>E</kbd> key **before**(or in the same frame as) hitting the tree.

I would rather expect that you want to first move close to the tree and **then press** <kbd>E</kbd> in order to cut it.

---

You should rather use [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html)

> Sent each frame where another object is within a trigger collider attached to this object (2D physics only).

in order to listen for the E key as long as you are within the trigger. I would then also use [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) in order to handle the press only once instead of every frame.

Otherwise you would do

```c#
anim.SetTrigger("TreeDamage");    
treeHp = treeHp -1;
```

ever frame while holing E down which is A) frame-rate-dependent and B) probabl not what you want to do here.

```c#
public float cooldownDuration;
private bool coolDown;

// Listen for the key as long as you stay in the collider
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(!coolDown && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        TakeDmg();
        Destroytree();

        StartCoroutine(CoolDown());
    }
}

IEnumerator CoolDown()
{
    coolDown = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownDuration);

    coolDown = false;
}
```

---

As alternative if you actually want to continue cutting while holding down <kbd>E</kbd> you could do it like

```c#
// Adjust in the Inspector: Seconds to wait before next cut
public float cutInterval = 1f;
private bool colliderExitted;

// Listen for the key as long as you stay in the collider
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        StartCoroutine(CuttingRoutine())
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    colliderExitted = true;
}

private IEnumerator CuttingRoutine()
{
    colliderExitted = false;
    while(!colliderExitted && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("TreeDamage");    
        treeHp = treeHp -1;

        // Add a delay before the next iteration
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(cutInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need a box collider with is trigger on, on the player, for this to work?

Comment: it worked when I added the anim, Thank you so so much, I stood yesterday like 2 or 3 hours to figure out this problem

Comment: I have another little question, wherein the code should I add a timer, and how can I add it, Im kinda new to coding

Comment: You should in the Inspector adjust the `cutInterval` .. that is the timer (see second solution below)

Comment: but I used ur first advice with the private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other), bcz I want the player to spam the e key

Comment: well then what exactly is the timer for?

Comment: the timer is for the player animation to end, like u press e, the player animation begins, the timer starts, the player animation ends and then u can press again e.

Comment: ok so basicall you would need to know the duration of the animation .. that's quite tricky actually ^^ But you could just start a timer routine (updated the answer) just set the `cooldownDuration` to the according seconds to wait

Comment: It works, thanks so much again, now i just need to spawn the logs